# Objective-C Formatting CGFloat

Tags: objective-c

Code
   CGFloat a=3.45378;

I want change the result to 
   CGFloat a=3.45f; only 2 precision

I know how printf works. but I don't know how to do this just keep 2 precision.

Comment: You want to convert it to string with only 2 decimals? u can do 1.2f, for that

Comment: i wont to change to string. I only want the new float only show 2 precision

Comment: lol...you dont want  to change to string then? or you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lose the extra precision, and round to the nearest two decimals, follow these steps:

- Multiply your number by 100 : 345.378
- Round your number to the nearest integer : 345
- Divide your number by 100 : 3.45