# work out percentage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

I am using the following code to work out the percentages of two numbers, could some on please help me remove the decimal numbers off `pcntNo` and `pcntYes`

```
//Work out percentages
int yes = [currentYes intValue];
int no = [currentNo intValue];
int total = yes + no;
int pcntYes = (yes / total) * 100;
int pcntNo = (no / total) * 100;
```

It always returns 0

Also i want it with no decimal places if that is possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's "decimal numbers"? If you mean fractional part, you won't have those - your percentages are stored as integers. By the way, you want slightly different arithmetics:

```
int pcntYes = (yes * 100) / total;
int pcntNo = (no *100) / total;
```

Otherwise, integer division will yield only zeros.

Comment: how would i then get the decimal version of pcntNo for a uiprogressview so it is like 0.56 etc

Comment: float pcntNo = (float)no / total;

Answer (score 0):

Use the floorf function from math.h:

```
 int pcntYes = floorf((yes / total) * 100);
```

Comment: how would i then get the decimal version of pcntNo for a uiprogressview so it is like 0.56 etc

Comment: CGFloat pcntYes = 0.00f; pcntYes = floorf((yes / total) * 100);

Comment: And if you need to truncate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208412/objective-c-formating-cgfloat